# Validating token in client application

Tags: validation, jwt, identityserver3

I have an application which accepts JWTtoken and go through the claims and respond to the request. Once I receive the JWTtoken, I want to validate whether it is issued by the Identity server which I trust.
Any idea how an application can perform JWTtoken validation?
an application simply make call:
/connect/identitytokenvalidation?token=&client_id= and get the token validation done?
Do I need to create TokenClient instance to call RequestAssertionAsync? or I can simply make http get request by passing token value in the query string?
I can get the token value with the following way:
Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"];

Any sample would be of a great help.

Comment: Is your "application" a web api? and the token an access token?

Comment: yes, I am actually using the sample web api deployed as part of the IdentityServer3 samples. And the token is access token. I am still trying to find how to validate the token. Any sample would be of great help.

Comment: I also tried calling the url: https://myserver/IdentityServer/connect/accessTokenValidation by passing the token value in the form as shown below:  var form = new
            {
                token = Request.GetOwinContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"]

            };   var resp = PostForm(TestUrl, form); but the response is coming as bad request.

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is running in a Katana pipeline then you can use either the Microsoft JWT bearer authentication middleware, or you can use the IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation middleware. Either of these will be the proper validation.

If you don't want to use those and do it manually, then you can use the Microsoft JwtSecurityTokenHandler class to perform the validation.

Here's the relevant lines of code from our sample web api

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/SampleAspNetWebApi/Startup.cs

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44333/core",
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "write" },
            });
```

Comment: Yes, I have this call: UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication placed in my Application2 startup.cs. I am wondering when the incoming token gets validated... when Application1 is calling Application2, Application1 will pass the token to Application2. So if I have the above code in Application2, is it enough? the token automatically gets validated?

Comment: also I don't see that the API: app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication making call to IdenityServer to validate the token. So I am wondering when the token gets validated